# How to Connect Azure Data Factory to ADLS Gen2 store?

Tags: azure

Can you please help me How to connect Azure Data Factory To Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2?.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you want to move some data to ADL G2, here is the ref
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/load-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a linked service in the Azure Data Factory UI.

1. Go to the **Manage** tab in the Azure Data Factory UI and select **Linked services**.

[image: Azure Data Factory UI]

2. Type **Azure Data Lake Storage** in the search bar and select the connector.

[image: Linked Services]

3. Configure the linked service details. When you are done, test it and create your linked service.
   [image: Azure Data Lake Gen 2 Linked Service]

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage?tabs=data-factory

Answer (score -1):

Please create a Linked service using managed identity or sas token or secret key

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks Sumit Verma